# Remove text in parentheses except if text contains keyword

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have strings:

> text1 (key) text2
>
> text1 (key) text2 (some other text)
>
> [key] text.. text.. [some other text]
>
> and so on

I want to remove "some other text" with parentheses, but not (key) and [key].

(key), [key] will always be the same. Always "key".

I have this code, which match every brackets, parantheses, curly brackets...

```
\(.*?\)|\[(.*?)\]|\{(.*?)\}
```

I just want to exclude [key] (key) from match.
Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's fixed text, not a pattern, you don't need regex.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @codeMan No, `[^key]` doesn't match `k`, `e` or `y`, not `key` as a keyword.

Comment: It should be: text1 (key) text2, 

text1 (key) text2, 

[key] text.. text..

Comment: `\((?!key\)).*?\)` and the same for other delimiters.

Comment: Do you also have lines like [these](https://regex101.com/r/oY8nV2/1) where then currently accepted answer doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[({\[](?!key).*?[)\]}]
```

You can do this easily with this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/23

textpop-up

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[({\[](?!key).*?[)\]}]', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "\n\n text1 (key) text2\n\n text1 (key) text2 (some other text)\n\n [key] text.. text.. [some other text]\n\n and so on\n"
subst = ""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: Welp, I'm not one to judge!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use negative lookahead assertion. `\((?!key\))(.*?)\)` negative lookahead after `\(` asserts that there isn't a string `key)` present just after to `(` symbol. If yes, then capture the contents within `()` braces. Likewise the same for other two brackets.

```
>>> s = """text1 (key) text2

text1 (key) text2 (some other text) {key}

[key] text.. text.. [some other text]"""
>>> re.findall(r'\((?!key\))(.*?)\)|\[(?!key\])(.*?)\]|\{(?!key\})(.*?)\}', s)
[('some other text', '', ''), ('', 'some other text', '')]
>>> m = re.findall(r'\((?!key\))(.*?)\)|\[(?!key\])(.*?)\]|\{(?!key\})(.*?)\}', s)
>>> [j for i in m for j in i if j]
['some other text', 'some other text']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aM4iH1/3)